# WPF Prism initializing tabs with ICollection using Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a tab view model, it works by when you create a new tab, it generates a new instance of Class B.

However, there is the possibility that the program can load a file which, using JSON, gets an instance of Class A which has a collection of Class B.

How can I instantiate the tabs with the existing collection of Class B Object? Preferably still using Navigation instead of View Injection/Discovery.

Here is my code for adding a new tab

```
   public void AddTabCommandAction()
   {
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TabRegion, "ClassBView");
   }
```

And my class B viewmodel.

```
   public ClassBViewModel(ClassB b){
     _b = b;
   }
```

I am using UnityContainer to resolve types of ClassB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but I solved the issue by using the Navigation journal.

The on navigated to method in the tabs view model

```
 foreach (var item in list)
        {
            AddTabCommandAction(item);
        }
```

Passing in the item as a naviagaion parameter

OnNavigatedTo method of the tab view model

```
   var classB= navigationContext.Parameters["ClassB"];
        if (classB!= null)
            _classB= (ClassB) classB;
```